# How do i repair taskbar freeze

Tags: freeze, taskbar

Every time I turn on my PC I need to click right click on my taskbar and click either lock or unlock to see anything or when i turn on an app and it just doesnt appear and i have to do the same as written before. Also, I tried to restart the taskbar but nothing worked.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.